# intel HD Graphic 4400 For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

How to Install Driver intel HD Graphic on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ?

How can I install it from terminal ?

Comment: You don't have to.

Comment: refer this site https://allanbogh.com/2016/01/05/ubuntu-16-04-installing-the-intel-graphics-drivers-using-the-intel-graphics-installer-for-linux/

Comment: @anandmbs No, you don't need to do that. From Intel's webpage at https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0: "This release of the Graphics Installer is targeted at Ubuntu 15.10 or Fedora 23.  Ubuntu 16.04 is already current with the latest Q1 2016 Intel Graphics stack and therefore no Graphics Installer is needed."

Comment: If then, just update your ubuntu with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

From https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0:

> Ubuntu 16.04 is already current with the latest Q1 2016 Intel Graphics stack and therefore no Graphics Installer is needed.

This means that no additional installation is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Intel usually release the linux installers 2 months later than the graphics stack. The 2016Q2 was released just 4 days ago, so I don't expect the installers until August.